# Is there a way to mass-check Checkboxes when updating a Profile's Object's Field Level Security?

Tags: javascript, profile

Is there a way to mass-check Checkboxes when updating a Profile's Object's Field Level Security?  When setting Field Level Security for a Site's Profile (or any other Profile), I have some objects that have 300+ fields, and there isn't a way to mass check or un-check all "Read" or "Edit" Checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Check All](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/check-all/nnbihdpkeohjdfncchjhidbbonnihaob?hl=en) Google Chrome extension for this.

And I just noticed there is also a [Salesforce Admin Check All](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-admin-check-al/efcahpjiijlbojmfmaceicchnhkgdkje?hl=en) extension available to add the UI that Salesforce should have.

Comment: aargh - wish I had known about this the other day. Does your blog contain an updated list of all the tools you use?

Comment: @crop1645 There isn't much I use beyond the Force.com IDE (I know I should change to MavensMate but I used to develop Eclipse Plugins for a living so Eclipse has sentimental value) and Chrome's Developer Tools. The rubbish profile UI forced me to go look for something to help or face repetitive strain injury.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript will do the job if you can use a 3rd-party Plug-in on your Browser that allows you to execute the JavaScript.

First, it's good to note that Salesforce has a couple different UIs depending on the age of your org.  And then you may also have a different UI between Production and Sandbox.

For the UI pictured below, the URL will be something like

```
https://[org-name].my.salesforce.com/[profileId]?s=ObjectsAndTabs&o=[objectId]
```

I have my JavaScript load for pages like `https://*.salesforce.com/*s=ObjectsAndTabs*` where `*` is a wildcard.

Here's a screenshot of the Profile UI which seems to be the latest version:

[image: Salesforce Profile UI Screenshot]

Inspecting the Checkboxes, you'll see that their `id`s end with `fls_read_ck` and `fls_edit_ck` for Read and Edit respectively.  And also, the `th` have `id`s that end eith `fls_readheader` and `fls_editheader` for Read and Edit respectively.  So hear's the idea:

- With jQuery, add a click event to the the `th`s where it will confirm you want to check all of the column's Chexkboxes.
- If you click <kbd>Ok</kbd>, use jQuery to get the closest `table` of the clicked `th`, and then get all not disabled input Checkboxes that have its `id` with the similar ending as the `th` does, and check those Checkboxes.  Then set a Boolean variable to false so that the next time the `th` is clicked, it asks you to un-check the Checkboxes instead.

Here's the JavaScript.  I use a JavaScript class since the Read and the Edit methods are nearly identical.  I also add a yellow background to the `th`s on a hover event so the user knows there's something special with the `th`s.

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

function FieldPermissionType(name, idEnding){
  this.name = name;
  this.idEnding = idEnding;
  this.checkAll = true;
}

FieldPermissionType.prototype.getThQuery = function(){
  return 'th[id$="' + this.idEnding + 'header"].headerRow';
};
FieldPermissionType.prototype.getCheckboxQuery = function(){
  return 'input[id$="' + this.idEnding + '_ck"]:not(:disabled)';
};
FieldPermissionType.prototype.execute = function(){
  var isChecked = this.checkAll;
  $(this.getThQuery()).closest('table').find(this.getCheckboxQuery()).each(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', isChecked);
  });
  this.checkAll = !this.checkAll;
};

var FieldPermissionTypeMap = {
  Read : new FieldPermissionType('Read', 'fls_read'),
  Edit : new FieldPermissionType('Edit', 'fls_edit')
}

function massCheck(fieldPermissionTypeName){
  console.log('massCheck with fieldPermissionTypeName: ' + fieldPermissionTypeName);
  var fieldPermissionType = FieldPermissionTypeMap[fieldPermissionTypeName];
  console.log(fieldPermissionType);
  var confirmMessage = 'Do you want to ' + (fieldPermissionType.checkAll ? '' : 'un') + 'check all ' + fieldPermissionType.name + ' Checkboxes?';
  if(confirm(confirmMessage)){
    console.log('Execute confirmed.');
    fieldPermissionType.execute();
  } else {
    console.log('canceled...');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(FieldPermissionTypeMap['Read'].getThQuery()).click(function(){
    massCheck('Read');
  }).hover(
    function(){
      $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }, function(){
      $(this).css('background-color', '#F2F3F3');
    }
  );
  $(FieldPermissionTypeMap['Edit'].getThQuery()).click(function(){
    massCheck('Edit');
  }).hover(
    function(){
      $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }, function(){
      $(this).css('background-color', '#F2F3F3');
    }
  );
});

console.log('Mass Check Site Field Permissions loaded.');
```

To have the Profile Page execute the JavaScript, I needed a 3rd-party extension/add-on for my Browswer.  I use Firefox, and there's a great Add-on called "Greasemonkey" (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) that'll do the job.  In the Greasemonkey script, I get jQuery from a CDN (e.g. https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery), and the script looks like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Mass Check Profile Field Permissions
// @namespace   https://*.salesforce.com/*s=ObjectsAndTabs*
// @include     https://*.salesforce.com/*s=ObjectsAndTabs*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
[the above JavaScript]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this little gem for change sets:

```
document.onmouseover = function(e){ if (e.target.type == 'checkbox') e.target.click() };
```

Just make sure to execute it in the correct iFrame. Just do a right click and inspect inside the table or section where your checkboxes are. That should open the console in the correct frame. Then copy/paste and have fun hovering...

No jQuery necessary!

Answer (score 0):

This is X-Y problem question. Actually, instead of making tweaks for mass check checkboxes on standard layout, one can just invent and publish an AppExchange package with header checkbox functionality where admin user can click checkbox in a header row to check all checkboxes.

I have just released recently [a package called BofPerMan](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FtWcBUAV) which gives a flexibility to bulk update Object and Field Level permission

I have shot [a promo video describing capabilities of my package](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKkrckTSbxM) BofPerMan which is published on AppExchange.

Here I discuss a possible case of a content management application consisting of two custom objects Book and Movie and a task to set Modify All and Create permission to both of these objects to two custom profiles, Content Manager User and Media Administrator and to Content Manager custom permission set. While this might be nasty and complicated task to perform using standard UI, it can be achieved in few clicks using BofPerMan package! Watch and see this in action